# Respond to message received by TestProbe

Tags: scala, akka

I want to mock an Actor that receives a message:

```
GetAllJobs()
```

and replies with a message:

```
ReturnAllJobs(jobHash: Map[Int, Job])
```

I want to do something like this with TestProbe:

```
resultReceiver.onMessage(GetAllJobs()).reply(ReturnAllJobs(jobHash))
```

So how can I mock the actor using TestProbe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Autopilot` might help. See an example below:

```
  val probe = TestProbe()
  probe.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot {
    def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any): TestActor.AutoPilot = {
      msg match {
        case GetAllJobs => 
          sender ! ReturnAllJobs(jobHash)
          TestActor.KeepRunning
        case x => TestActor.KeepRunning
      }
  })
```

See [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#Auto-Pilot) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

And for Java fans using Akka

```
    final TestProbe simpleActor = TestProbe.apply(akkaSystem);

        simpleActor.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot() {
            public TestActor.AutoPilot run(ActorRef sender, Object msg) {
                if (msg instanceof DoAction) {
                    sender.tell(new Response(), ActorRef.noSender());
                    log.info("Respond to {}", sender);
                }
                return noAutoPilot();
            }
        });
```